# ionic3 sqlite error while compiling the app on xcode

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

hello i got this errors while im compiling my app : 
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SQLitePlugin and duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SQLitePlugin my pakckege.josn file have these packages:

```
"cordova-plugin-sqlite-2": "~1.0.4",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.1.3",
"pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite"
```

and these plugins:

```
"cordova-sqlite-storage"
"cordova-plugin-sqlite-2"
```

i dont know where is the conflicts

Answer (score 0):

From the Github issue page from the author :
[Github issue page](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2/issues/49)

> Those two libraries are competitors, not complementary packages. They both add the same object, called SQLitePlugin. ideally you should use one or the other, not both.

So you should remove one of these two plugins, either `cordova-sqlite-storage`, either `cordova-plugin-sqlite-2`